# Trouble settings up If statements in OnTriggerEnter/OnTriggerStay

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have 4 objects (A, B, C, D). All are onTriggerStay along with tags of their names as well. A question would pop up and they have to answer it by colliding with their answer(A, B, C, D), but if statements are not working correctly for some reason I tried OnTriggerStay and OnTriggerEnter but none of them. I tried changing if statements to else if but no luck. These scripts are attached to 4 gameobjects(A, B, C, D) I have attached a small clip to demonstrate the problem and my script.

[Video Clip](https://www.kapwing.com/videos/63d3a501580d2d0148fb7e45)

Thank you

```cs
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using Unity.VisualScripting;
    using UnityEngine;
    
    public class Question1 : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public GameObject A;
        public GameObject B;
        public GameObject C;
        public GameObject D;
    
        public GameObject fluSyringe;
        public GameObject virusA;
        public GameObject virusD;
        public GameObject virusC;
    
        private void OnTriggerStay(Collider other)
        {
            if (CompareTag("A") == other.CompareTag("Player"))
            {
                Debug.Log("A");
                virusA.SetActive(true);
            }
    
            if (CompareTag("B") == other.CompareTag("Player"))
            {
                Debug.Log("B");
                fluSyringe.SetActive(true);
            }
    
            if (CompareTag("C") == other.CompareTag("Player"))
            {
                Debug.Log("C");
                virusC.SetActive(true);
            }
    
            if (CompareTag("D") == other.CompareTag("Player"))
            {
                Debug.Log("D");
                virusD.SetActive(true);
            }
    
            else
            {
                Debug.Log("ABCD");
            }
        }
    
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your if-statements have side effects. This statement (like the others)

```
if (CompareTag("A") == other.CompareTag("Player"))
```

will also evaluate to `true` if `CompareTag("A")` and `other.compareTag("Player")` will both evaluate to `false`. How can this happen? Watching your video one can see that when you trigger the letter A, the other viruses at C and D will fall down the moment the virus at A touches the letter A. Thus i assume your virus object has a collider on it which leads to `other.CompareTag("Player")` being `false`. The script placed at A will now trigger all if-statements with `CompareTag(X)` where X is not `"A"`. The syringe is a smaller object and i assume its collider is not touching letter B when falling down, hence in the video it looks like that it works for letter B. But that is just lucky not triggering the side effects in this case.
Assuming you want to keep the whole logic in this one script (i am not sure if this is feasible), you need to split the if-conditions:

```
        // exemplary shown for A
        if (CompareTag("A") {
            if (other.CompareTag("Player")) {
                Debug.Log("A");
                virusA.SetActive(true);
            }
        }
```

Comment: After reading your text I moved the virus object little further so they are not colliding with A, B, C, D. and it seems to solve the problem. Thank you I would have never guessed this

Comment: Ok cool. But you should really rewrite the if-statements. This side effect will occur with any other objects and come back at you.

Comment: I would actually invert the check and have the `if(other.CompareTag("Player"))` the out most .. also for your own tag I would rather simply use an enum instead of relying on the string/hash based tag system

Comment: Turns out it is creating a little problem I will have to rewrite my if-statement. I will get on it right now. Thank you